# How to create a flexbox grid with a column span and spacing between elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexbox grid which should look like that [image]

The basic grid layout is pretty easy to create, but I have a very hard time adding the spacing between the elements. As you can see in the code snippet, the spacing in the second line is not working properly.

```css
#flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
}

.rowContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 16px;
}

.thirdElement {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.twoThirdsElement {
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexContainer">
  <div class="rowContainer">
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowContainer">
    <div class="twoThirdsElement">
    </div>
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a three column grid with the fourth item spanning two colums.

Here's a simplified version. Obviously you'll want to style the items as you need them.

```css
#flexContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 16px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
}

#flexContainer>* {
  background-color: red;
}

.twoThirdsElement {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexContainer">
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div class="twoThirdsElement">
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the `grid-template-columns` line and the flexContainer/twoThirdsElement changes

Comment: The grid-template-columns is telling the system what columns there are in a row and saying that the columns are each to have 1fr width (that means they divide the available width up between them). The twoThirdsElement is just saying that that element starts in column 1 and spans two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS grid

```css
#flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px;
}

.rowContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 16px;
}

.thirdElement {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.twoThirdsElement {
  grid-column:span 2;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexContainer">
  <div class="rowContainer">
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowContainer">
    <div class="twoThirdsElement">
    </div>
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You not need to `<div class="rowContainer">`. It fixes only with one `flex` property for `#flexContainer`.

```css
#flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: calc(80px + (600px / 20)); /* (600px/20) == 5% of 600px. result = 80px + 5%(600px). it is for a gap between rows that is equal with gap: 5%; for columns.*/
  align-content: space-between;
  gap: 5%;
  width: 600px;
}

.thirdElement {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.twoThirdsElement {
  flex-basis: 65%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexContainer">
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
    <div class="twoThirdsElement">
    </div>
    <div class="thirdElement">
    </div>
</div>
```